# Reference values from other tables

Tags: sql

Assume I have two tables, `customer` and `watched`.

`watched` contains the column `custID`, which is a list of different customer id #'s.

`customer` contains the columns `custID` `fname` and `lname`.

I would like to count the number of occurrences of each `custID` in `watched`, but rather than returning the ID of each customer along with the counts, I would like to return columns `custID lname fname` and then the count in a new column.

I currently have it working with the return format as `custID` and then the count, i'm not sure how to reference the `customer` table to get the output that I would like. I'm very new to learning SQL, sorry if this is trivial. Here's what I have:

```
SELECT w.custID, count(custID)
    FROM watched w 
GROUP by custID
ORDER BY custID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a join? Something like;

```
SELECT
    c.custID,
    c.fname,
    c.lname,
    count(*) AS NumberOfWatched
FROM Watched w
INNER JOIN Customer c
    ON w.custID = c.custID
GROUP BY
    c.custID,
    c.fname,
    c.lname
```

As a side note, please consider naming your columns properly...

I cry when I see abbreviated names for no reason